# Combining two VBA tasks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to combine two functions. I have a VBA script which goes through a set range and sorts all the text column by column alphabetically.

```
Sub SortIndividualRows()
' Sorts rows within a list from A-Z
' Run Clean all first to avoid sorting blanks
' Set maximum range to avoid sorting too many rows

    Dim rngFirstRow As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("A1:NS1")
    For Each rng In rngFirstRow
        With ws.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, Order:=xlAscending
            'assuming there are no blank cells..
            .SetRange ws.Range(rng, rng.Range("A87").End(xlUp))
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Apply
        End With
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'd like to combine this with a script to then sort each column by color. I recorded a macro when I sorted manually and looked at the code the recording generated. I'm trying to figure out how I could take the generated code and combine it with the above function.

```
Sub sortColor()
'
' sortColor Macro
' Goes through a range of selected cells and sorts by color, setting green cells (matches) above those with no match (red text)
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("F4:F88"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, _
        239, 206)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("F3:F88")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you want to run one module then the other straight away afterwards? or do you want the action of the second module to run each time the for loop completes?

To run one directly after the other:

Sub SortIndividualRows()
' Sorts rows within a list from A-Z
' Run Clean all first to avoid sorting blanks
' Set maximum range to avoid sorting too many rows

```
Dim rngFirstRow As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("A1:NS1")
For Each rng In rngFirstRow
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, Order:=xlAscending
        'assuming there are no blank cells..
        .SetRange ws.Range(rng, rng.Range("A87").End(xlUp))
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Apply
    End With
Next rng

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("F4:F88"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, _
    239, 206)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("F3:F88")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To run the second module each time the for loop completes:

```
Sub SortIndividualRows()
' Sorts rows within a list from A-Z
' Run Clean all first to avoid sorting blanks
' Set maximum range to avoid sorting too many rows

Dim rngFirstRow As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("A1:NS1")
For Each rng In rngFirstRow
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, Order:=xlAscending
        'assuming there are no blank cells..
        .SetRange ws.Range(rng, rng.Range("A87").End(xlUp))
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Apply
    End With


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("F4:F88"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, _
    239, 206)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("F3:F88")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Next rng

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically the way the first sub works is that it sorts A-Z the first column (within the max range set) then moves on to the next column. What I'd like to do, is sort A-Z, then sort by Color, then repeat on the next column. I'm not sure if that's faster of the most efficient way. I'm fine with whatever is the most efficient solution.

Comment: Also, the second module isn't good because it will readily sort range F3:F88 because that was the selected range when I recorded. Module 1 behaves perfectly, as it moves one column at a time within the range. I'd like to do the same by sort by cell color. I just don't know enough VBA to figure out what I need to take within the second module and implement into the first one.